# Mystery Overflow (Error 6)

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

I have a sub routine that immediately errors out for reasons I can't understand.

First line in the routine tries to load a value into a variable and it errors out.

```
UPCTGT = CLng(Sheets("Settings").Range("C3").Value)
```

The value in cell C3 is 3800040260 ..Why would that cause an overflow error?

Comment: An signed long integer or **Long** has a range of –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 ([Data Type Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). You're trying to stuff in 3,800,040,260.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Long` is a 32-bit signed data type. The largest number you can produce with 32-bits (signed) is **`2,147,486,647`**

---

**TL;DR**

32 bits refers to 32 bits *of memory*

The reason **`2,147,486,647`** is the largest number available is because:

```
'// Dec to Binary
2,147,486,647 = 11111111111111111111111111111111
2,147,486,648 = 100000000000000000000000000000000
                                                ^
                                     '// That's a 33rd bit
```

That 33rd bit ***overflows*** the amount of memory available for that data type - hence the overflow error.

---

A `Double` however, is a 64 bit signed integer and has plenty of room for you :)

Answer (score 0):

needed to cast as double. Although I am not sure why Long isn't enough. I thought that data type had much more potential